# Request to Web Service (POST)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to send a request to my web service that I've created (http://localhost/WebServices/DisplayResolution.asmx?op=Get). I believe the web service requires POST to be sent.

How can I do this from my C# desktop client? Should I use SOAP as the web service recommends?!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l02BZ.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use Visual Studio to create a the necessary proxy classes to consume your web service by adding a "Service reference" to your client project.

This article on [Consuming Web (asmx) Services](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/consuming-data-web-asmx-service.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I'd rather stay away from that as my URI will change depending on the users configuration (e.g. the server name will change)

Comment: A service's URI is likely to change in a production environment, so this is configurable, of course. It depends on the technology you end up using (WCF or the older Wsdl.exe), but you can either pass the URL as a constructor parameter to the client proxy or set it using the `URL` property.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Defiantly the right answer, and I didn't think it'd be anywhere near this easy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class to make this call.

Also since this SOAP web service there is nothing to stop you from creating web reference of this web service in to your applicaiton and use the proxy class.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? I'm pretty new to C# so example code would be great!